# How do you only show part of a webpage in iOS web view when there is a link?

Tags: ios, swift, web

I'm building an iOS app in Xcode using Swift. One of the app's pages has to be a link to my company's existing webpage. This webpage has a calculator widget that, when info is put in, leads the user to another page with the results.

I need to show the webpage in web view but make it less obvious that it's a webpage. It has to look like it's a dedicated part of the app so I need to only show the page (and the page it links to) information. No header. No footer.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could run javascript from the web view after it finishes loading.

try this:

```
let objectId = "calculator"
let javascript: String = "var p = document; var d = document.getElementById('\(objectId)'); p.innerHTML = ''; p.appendChild(d);"
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: javascript)
```

where objectId is the id of the only thing you want to show within the webView